# Chrome extension popup page stops updating when background script is added

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I've been working on a Chrome extension and I noticed that my Bootstrap spinner stops spinning properly and my DOM won't update when I add a background script to my `manifest.json`

Duplicated this issue in a simple dummy extension which I'll share below. It doesn't appear to be a Bootstrap-specific thing as DOM updates I'm making in my other extension are showing up in some cases 10 seconds after logging indicates the DOM has been updated. To make the DOM update I have to move the mouse around, click a button, or highlight some text. Another interesting way to keep the spinner going is to open DevTools, go to Elements, and hover over something.

**Evidence:**

- [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiSq9.gif)
- [After `background.js` added to `manifest.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI1fd.gif)

**Notes:**

- Doesn't seem to matter if `persistent` is `true` or `false`
- Doesn't seem to matter if `permissions` are specified
- Issue was still present when I downloaded Bootstrap [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.3.1/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist.zip) and linked to `bootstrap.min.css` in my `popup.html`
- I left my `background.js` intentionally blank, but perhaps some code is needed there to get rid of the issue (like a listener). I tried adding this to my `background.js` but it didn't seem to affect anything:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  });
  ```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "spinner-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {       // Comment this out to see it work properly
    "scripts": [        // Comment this out to see it work properly
      "background.js"   // Comment this out to see it work properly
    ],                  // Comment this out to see it work properly
    "persistent": false // Comment this out to see it work properly
  },                    // Comment this out to see it work properly
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spinner Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="h1 center">Spinner Test</h1>
      <div id="spinner" class="btn btn-block">
        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        &nbsp;Loading...
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
// Nothing
```

Comment: If you're on MacOS and using an external display, it's a bug in Chrome, https://crbug.com/971701

Comment: @wOxxOm Bingo. Thanks a bunch.